# GTK Basic Window App on Mac - Warning, Deprecated

Tags: c, macos, gtk

I'm running a basic GTK app from the GTK website's tutorials, and I'm getting the following warning:-

*** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.

I've installed the gtk+ and gtk+3 packages with brew. Here is the code from the file:-

```
    #include 

    static void
    activate (GtkApplication* app,
              gpointer        user_data)
    {
      GtkWidget *window;

      window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
      gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
      gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);
      gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    }

    int
    main (int    argc,
          char **argv)
    {
      GtkApplication *app;
      int status;

      app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
      g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
      status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
      g_object_unref (app);

      return status;
    }
```

I'm running OS X 10.10.5, MacBook Pro 13in Retina.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Replace "userSpaceScaleFactor" with "convertRectToBacking" like the warning say. On Linux with GCC it compiles fine.

Comment: That's nowhere to be found in his code. Does the warning happen at runtime?

Comment: Yeah, it happens at runtime

Comment: Everything I've found on that error implies it comes from OS X itself. I don't see anything in GTK+ that calls `-[NSView userSpaceScaleFactor]`; it does call `-[NSScreen userSpaceScaleFactor]`, which I think is unrelated... That being said, file a bug with the GTK+ developers at http://bugzilla.gnome.org/; maybe they can look into it too.